# Iteration over pool.imap_unordered

Tags: python, iterator, multiprocessing

Consider very simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing import Pool
import random

def f(x):
    return x*x

def sampleiter(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
     rand = random.random()
     yield rand
     num += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    for item in pool.imap_unordered(f, sampleiter(100000000000000), 20):
     print item
    pool.close
```

While running in the terminal, Python leaking memory.
What could be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean leaking memory here?

Comment: Run program, run top, wait, memory consumption grows 30m, 60m, 300m, 1G...

Comment: @user1291515: Can you update your actual question with this last bit of information so that it is immediately clear how you are testing "memory leak"

Answer (score 4):

Output buffering isn't the problem (or at least, not the only one), because (a) the Python process itself grows in memory, and (b) if you redirect to `/dev/null` it still happens.

I think the issue is that when you print out the results, the pool is returning results much faster than they can be consumed, and so lots and lots of results are sitting in memory. If you look at [the source of the class that does this](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l590), intermediate results are stored in the `collections.deque` called `_items`; I'd wager that `_items` is getting huge.

I'm not entirely sure how to test this, though, because even though [`imap_unordered` returns an instance of this class](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l247) you still seem to only be able to get at the generator methods:

```
In [8]: r = pool.imap_unordered(f, sampleiter(1e8), 20)

In [9]: print dir(r)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__',
 '__init__', '__iter__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
 '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
 'close', 'gi_code', 'gi_frame', 'gi_running', 'next', 'send', 'throw']
```

**Update:** if you add a `time.sleep(.01)` to `f()`, memory usage stays completely constant. So, yeah, the problem is that you're producing results faster than you can use them.

(As an aside: you mean `pool.close()` at the end of your code sample; `pool.close` is just a reference to the function and doesn't actually call it.)

Comment: You are actually probably right. I tested it by simply replacing the print with a sleep, and the memory grows relative to how long you sleep and force the pool to build its internal cache larger and larger.

Comment: True, small sleep makes issue gone. Thanks for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The only variable I see here that causes the memory leak is your print statement. When I replace `print item` with `pass`, the memory stays low and constant. I am not sure exactly what is happening under the hood when you do print, but its obviously stacking something up and not freeing. Also, when I lower your chunk size to 1, the memory increases much more slowly (obviously), but also takes longer. So it does multiply the memory usage.

#### Update

Found this as a specific reference to memory usage increasing due to the terminal's history buffer (not the python process itself): [Memory leak when running python in Mac OS Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646331/memory-leak-when-running-python-in-mac-os-terminal)

Comment: Ok, output buffer sounds reasonable, still even with >/dev/null it grows relatively fast...

Comment: @user1291515 I don't think this is the whole story: see my answer.